# Arc length integral with a polynomial of the second degree

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, arc-length

If $f(x)=3.5x^2-2.1x+4.6$ then its arc length from $x=2$ to $x=5$  is given by $$\int_2^5 \sqrt{49x^2-29.4 x+5.41} \,dx$$

The general formula is:
$$\int_a^b \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} \,dx$$

How do I calculate the first integral without a calculator or a software? Trigonometric substitutions won't work, will they?

Comment: Have you tried completing the square, factoring, and making a substitution?

Comment: You will need to use a hyperbolci substitution

Comment: @DavidQuinn: Trigonometric substitutions work (albeit a bit messy).

Comment: It can't be factorized. What substitution should I use?